# docker container startとローカルPCの同期について

Tags: docker

コンテナ作成時に、-vオプションを使用し、ローカルのディレクトリやファイルをコンテナ内に同期させることができますが、1回、コンテナを停止し、ローカル側で、ファイル等の修正を行い、docker container startで起動したとき、修正等を行ったファイルも、再起動を行ったコンテナ内に同期される（同じ状態）のでしょうか？

同期させて起動（start）する場合には、docker container startで何かオプションが必要になるのでしょうか？

## dockerfile

```
FROM python
WORKDIR /tmp/mydir
COPY ./ex01 /tmp/mydir/
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

## コンテナ作成・起動コマンド

```
docker container run -it --name py-01 -v ${PWD}/ex01:/tmp/mydir img_ex01_py_01
```

Comment: -vの後ろの指定方法によってはお答えしかねますし、回答する人が同じ操作を試せるように、再現性のある具体的なコマンドラインで質問して頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: dockerfileとコンテナ作成・起動のコマンドを編集にて追記致しました。

Comment: bind mountしてるだけなので、他のプロセスと同様に./ex01のファイルシステム上で同期されると思いますよ。コンテナ上のプロセスがexitした後、例えば
docker container start -i py-01
で同じコンテナ上でbashを起動した場合でも、すでに同期された状態です。

Comment: 最初から気になってはいたんですが、containerの内容をimageとしてcommitする範囲は、volume指定したりbind mountしたりする範囲を含みませんよ。あくまでコンテナの外側です。「同期」の意味が、imageとして保存されない範囲におけるコンテナが停止した時点の復元ということであれば、そんな機能はどこにもありません。

Comment: 今回、 ホストOS側（コンテナの外側）の${PWD}/ex01配下を コンテナ内の/tmp/mydirへ同期していると思うのですが？ ${PWD}/ex01配下でソースを変更しても再起動したコンテナには、変更部分が反映されていないということです。

Comment: docker containerは${PWD}/ex01をbind mountしてるだけですよ。コンテナ内の/tmp/mydirへのアクセスは、リアルタイムに${PWD}/ex01へのアクセスになるということです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントした点について、回答の方で再現できるコードを書きました。

ご提示頂いたdockerfileをDockerfileで用意して頂き、以下をhoge.shで保存してください。

```bash
mkdir ex01
docker build -t img_ex01_py_01 .
echo 'writing before the container start...' > ./ex01/hoge.txt
docker container run -it --name py-01 -v ${PWD}/ex01:/tmp/mydir img_ex01_py_01 bash
echo 'writing after the container stopped...' >> ./ex01/hoge.txt
docker container start -i py-01
docker container rm py-01
```

端末から以下のように実行してください(途中端末から入力する必要があります)。

```
$ bash -x hoge.sh
+ mkdir ex01
+ docker build -t img_ex01_py_01 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python
 ---> 00cd1fb8bdcc
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /tmp/mydir
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9a0978729a11
Step 3/4 : COPY ./ex01 /tmp/mydir/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6286728cb827
Step 4/4 : CMD ["/bin/bash"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 95d2976d0da2
Successfully built 95d2976d0da2
Successfully tagged img_ex01_py_01:latest
+ echo 'writing before the container start...'
+ docker container run -it --name py-01 -v /home/user/soj/92006/ex01:/tmp/mydir img_ex01_py_01 bash
root@682e70196520:/tmp/mydir# cat >>hoge.txt
aaaaa
root@682e70196520:/tmp/mydir# exit
exit
+ echo 'writing after the container stopped...'
+ docker container start -i py-01
root@682e70196520:/tmp/mydir# cat hoge.txt
writing before the container start...
aaaaa
writing after the container stopped...
root@682e70196520:/tmp/mydir# exit
exit
+ docker container rm py-01
py-01
$
```

最初のdocker container runで書き込んだ内容の前後に、dockerコンテナ外での書き込みが反映されていることが、docker container startで再開したcatで分かると思います。